# What is "Scanning for working copies"

Tags: ios, xcode

I just "upgraded" to Lion and Xcode 4.3.2 and now it says "Scanning for working copies" in the  status area in the title bar just below the project name.  It started doing this after automatically downloads iOS 5.1.  The progress bar sits their endlessly.  What is it doing and why?

Comment: See my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11871096/xcode-stuck-on-loading-revision-and-scanning-for-working-copies-when-usin/11902861#11902861

Answer (score 1):

New Lion's auto saves and Version feature saves every file in background and create versions for letter change and therefore following this feature new Xcode can also save versions of your project using following ways

1. A snapshot saves the current state of your project.
2. Source control repositories.(directly used in xcode)
3. An archive packages your products for distribution.

When xcode starts, it scans for the working copies or loads all know version in memory so that all version can be used for edit/update etc
For Lion : [Follow this](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4753)

For xcode: [Follow this](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/ToolsLanguages/Conceptual/Xcode4UserGuide/SCM/SCM.html)

Comment: How can I prevent Xcode from scanning for working copies.  I sent a project to a developer and he made some major changes.  When I try to open the project, I can never tell for sure which version Xcode is going to open.  I would prefer that it opened the file that I click to open rather than a copy that I had looked at previously.

Linda

Comment: It will open the same you opened, working copies save by Lion or xcode are on the file you opened, it doesn't mean that xcode will scan your other files/folders on your computer